# Entity framework and foreign key as string

Tags: c#, sql, database, entity-framework, foreign-key-relationship

I have following tables:

```
 Language
    Id (bigint, primary key)
    Name (nvarchar(100))
    Code (nvarchar(2))

  Article
    Id (bigint, primary key)
    LanguageCode (nvarchar(2), foreign key constraint to Language/Code)
    ...
```

My question: if I generate the model using entity framework 4, it doesn't generate the relation between Article/LanguageCode and Language/Code. Is this an entity framework limitation and should I also add LanguageId to Article table, or am I doing something totally wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: You are doing something wrong (not sure what). The relation should be there.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. Delete Id and make Code primary, or use Id as foreign.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that Language.Code is not the Primary key of the Language class.
In your model its allowed to have different Languages with the same Language.Code.

Another thing. From Business perspective its much better to have different articles depending on users culture, instead of language. Because a Language is not unique for a single culture, and all Business things like CurrencyFormat, DateFormat, Taxes and of course the Law are culture specific.

Comment: Why you need a Language.Id ? I think you need only Language.Code as a primary key? Is it a foreign key with 2 columns ? Your doing "Database-first" development ?

Comment: hm strange! I removed the id in Language and made Code primary key, now it works! Thanks!

Comment: Ive updated my answer. Maybe interesting for you. Its about your Businessmodel. You're welcome!

Comment: actually articles belong to a language, not a country. In Belgium we have three languages :)